# unset the path for the library used by FullCalendar

Tags: 7, javascript

I am using FullCalendar module to display some events. I had to modify the design of the calendar and the only solution was to alter the way javascript of fullcalendar displays events and so . Now i do not want that at an update of the fullcalendar, all the changes i have made to dissapear.My question is how can i unset the path of the current fullcalendar library and set the path to my own customized library ?

Comment: Try this: check where in the module the JavaScript library is getting included. Now change the path to your customized library

Comment: @subhojit777 i know where it is but how can i do it permanentlly ?

Comment: You need to change that in fullcalendar module

Comment: @subhojit777 and if the fullcalendar module is updated without me knowing about it ? It will not render my file anymore...

Comment: well this is the custom work you are doing in a contributed module, so you have to be careful when the module is updated

Comment: @subhojit777 well all your comments were not helpful at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this issue FullCalendar should support the Libraries API module - http://drupal.org/node/980886

Comment #7 is especially relevant I believe.

This means you should be able to use Libraries http://drupal.org/project/libraries to handle getting your customized version of the library to be used instead of the bundled one.

Ie. Make sure it is named the same as the original and stick it in sites/all/libraries

Answer (score 0):

When you update a module what ever changes you have done would automatically be over written. if you have just made changes to js then it would be better to add that JS to your theme rather than the module itself.

You could you the [hook_js_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7) (On Drupal 7) or [jsalter](http://drupal.org/project/jsalter) (On Drupal 6) in yout theme to remove the module specific js.

Comment: It will , but if there it is a hook or in theme something that rewrites an entry in the array then does not matter how much updates are made because it will rewrite the path everytime... The only problem is if the fullcalendar changes the entries in the array.

Comment: That would be an issue. But you could effectively remove all the js from the specific module. and add the js through theme.

Comment: Could you provide me an example of how could i do it ?

Comment: what version of drupla are you using?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JrEczaUm

Comment: That assumes that the file is in sites/all/modules/fullcalender folder. this would unset all the js files in the fullcalender module

Comment: Thank you for support, I am using drupal 7.I see how to unset but how do i add my file and how would fullcalendar know about it ?

Comment: You can use drupal_add_js - http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7

Comment: tried your solution but it does not seem to work ...

Comment: could you send me the code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/TxcG8ctY

Comment: is the name of your theme "theme" if not you need to replace that with the name of your theme.

Comment: lol i know that , in my code is replaced but for you i have changed back to theme ...

Comment: :-) which part of it is not working for you? the unsetting part or the adding part?

Comment: unset part , the file is still loaded after a dsm() call ( at the end of function off course).

Comment: have you checked if it is actually called in the page?